# how to apply changes when I don't have the unity plugin enables in ccsm

Tags: ccsm

I installed compizconfig-settings-manager so I can use my PC, but after checkmarking enable unity plugin, I realized there is no way to apply the changes and I am screwed and there is no way to use this PC without terminal. I have a pic, screenshots don't work without unity plugin so I used my camera [image: ccsm] please help me out, I can't do everything from terminal. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the gnome environment and use ccsm with it. that might work.